# Couldn't connect 2 networks in a single router

Tags: router, network

I made a topology which has 2 separate networks connected to a router, each network has 1 switch and 2 pc's. I took a screenshot of the topology: https://i.gyazo.com/f99231fc75a41faa3ccd0315859fd84f.png

Gig0/0/0 Network can ping the router while the Gig0/1/0 network can't, what is the reasoning? And what could i possibly do to make both of the networks ping each other?

```
hostname Router
!
!
no ip cef
no ip ipv6 cef
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/2
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0
switch mode access
switchport nonegotiate
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/1
switch mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/2
switch mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/3
switch mode access
!
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
!
router rip
! 
ip default gateway 192.168.2.254
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 0
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the configuration of your router.  Use the preformatted text option { }.

Comment: The reasoning if you made a mistake somewhere but since you didn't provide the configuration we cannot tell where.

Comment: I will do that now, thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface Gi 0/1/0 is a switchport (layer 2) interface, not layer 3.
You can either:

Change the interface to layer 3 and assign an IP address (on a new subnet).

```
interface gi 0/1/0
no switchport
ip address 1.2.3.4  255.255.255.0
no shut
```

Or, create a SVI (layer 3 interface for VLAN 1, since that's the VLAN Gi 0/1/0 is assigned to by default.

```
interface vlan 1
ip address 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.0
no shut
```

Answer (score 0):

`Gi0/1/0` is a switchport and it is not define any vlans which means it is using the default vlan.

You need to `no shut` the vlan1 and define the ip address on vlan1.